# Import KML to Postgis and preserve style

Tags: postgis, geoserver, leaflet, openlayers, kml

We have a number of KML files we have authored and are currently using Google to share with end users.

For future needs, we would like to import these documents into a Geo Spacial database (we choose PostGIS). We later want to be able to display these KMLs in client applications. We have not picked a client end rendering tool yet but it will likely be something like OpenLayers or Leaflet.

After experimenting with importing the KML to PostGIS using ogr2ogr we have found that the style specification in the KML (given in Style elements and linked to from features with StyleURL elements) are not being translated to the layer tables generated by the tool. We are able to reassemble the layers in a viewer like QGIS but since the styles do not translate we lose icons, colors, transparencies, etc.

Is there in option for ogr2ogr to import this data to PostGID? Or another compatible tool? What would be the logical step to preserve these styles and allow a client rendering tool like OpenLayers/Leaflet to display them in their original form?